# Is it good practice to change text to upper case using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an interesting observation today.  I found code that made text uppercase using CSS, instead of `toUpperCase()` in JavaScript, but this code made a test fail.  The test was asserting on if text was rendered; because of the text's case being changed in CSS and not JavaScript, there was an inconsistency between what is displayed and what the actual data was.

Is it then bad practice to change case in CSS under certain circumstances?

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer. It is personal choice.

Comment: If it's a presentation detail then css is appropriate. If it changes semantics then probably not..

Comment: @thebjorn. This is the correct answer, you should make it an answer.

Comment: As pygeek said before, you should add as much styling as you can with the CSS. 

The difference between the `text-transform: uppercase;` and `toUpperCase()` JavaScript method is that the JavaScript method is changing the value of a text, so if you, for example, using `toUpperCase()` method on an input it's value is going  to be uppercased string, whereas CSS only styles it and if the user inputs the lowercase values, it's value would still be lowercased string, but you'll see the uppercased text.

Answer (score 2):

It is preferable to do as much styling as possible in CSS. This makes your code more maintainable since you know where to look for style changes. Also, CSS is much faster than JavasScript.

There may be instances where you absolutely need to utilize javascript for dynamic styling. Best practice in this case would be to add or remove a class containing the styles you would like to apply to an element.

Comment: Projects with large CSS code could be way harder to maintain w/o the use of special CSS-authoring frameworks/tools.

Comment: Of course. SASS/LESS is preferable in many cases, but that's tangent to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Presentationally, one can always expect the text transformation to take place correctly in all modern browsers when one uses CSS, while if one relies on Javascript, you may find very rare cases where a user does not have Javascript enabled.